# Why my back propagation doesn't work ? (Trying to code a neural net with 2 layers from scratch for digit recognition)

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist

My problem is that my NN is not training, and I can't figure why. Is anyone can help ? Here is my code, I can describe more if you don't understand something. Thank you !

So first of all, I import digit recognition data base and split it in order to train and test.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
```

I want my labels to be vectors of size 10, here, my labels are just the digit that the image represents. So I must do a transformation, so that my matrix of labels has a "1" on each column on the coordinate corresponding to the feature. If the feature X_1 is a "3", on the 2th coordinate of the column 1 of the matrix will be a "1" and every others coordinate will be "0".

```
y_train1 = np.zeros((10,y_train.shape[0]))

  for i in range(0,y_train.shape[0]):
     y_train1[ y_train[i]  , i ] = 1    

x_train1 = np.transpose(x_train)
```

Then I create activation functions :

```
def sigmoid(Z):

   A = 1/(1+np.exp(-Z))
   cache = Z

   return A, cache

def relu(Z):

   A = np.maximum(0,Z)

   assert(A.shape == Z.shape)

   cache = Z 
   return A, cache
```

A function that initialize parameters with good dimensions :

```
def init (n_x, n_h, n_y):

   ##Initialisation aléatoire des poids et biais pour un réseau à 1 couche cachée##
   W1 = np.random.randn(n_h,n_x)*0.01
   b1 = np.zeros((n_h,1))
   W2 = np.random.randn(n_y,n_h)*0.01
   b2 = np.zeros((n_y,1))

   assert(W1.shape == (n_h, n_x))
   assert(b1.shape == (n_h, 1))
   assert(W2.shape == (n_y, n_h))
   assert(b2.shape == (n_y, 1))


   parameters = {"W1": W1,
              "b1": b1,
              "W2": W2,
              "b2": b2}

   return parameters
```

functions to do the linear foward activation :

```
def propa_avant(A,W,b):
   Z = np.dot(W,A) + b 
   assert(Z.shape == (W.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
   cache = (A,W,b)

   return Z, cache

def propa_avant_activ(A_prev, W, b, activation): 

   if activation =="sigmoid" : 
       Z, linear_cache = propa_avant(A_prev,W,b)
       A, activation_cache = sigmoid(Z)

   if activation =="relu":
       Z, linear_cache = propa_avant(A_prev,W,b)
       A, activation_cache = relu(Z)

   assert (A.shape == (W.shape[0], A_prev.shape[1]))

   cache = (linear_cache, activation_cache)

   return A, cache
```

Cross-Entropy cost function :

```
def fonction_cout(AL,Y): 

   m = Y.shape[1]
   cost = (-1/m)*np.sum(Y*np.log(AL)+(1-Y)*np.log(1-AL))

   cost = np.squeeze(cost)      
   assert(cost.shape == ())

   return cost
```

Derivatives of activation functions :

```
def relu_backward(dA, cache):

   Z = cache
   dZ = np.array(dA, copy=True) 


   dZ[Z <= 0] = 0

   assert (dZ.shape == Z.shape)

   return dZ

def sigmoid_backward(dA, cache):

   Z = cache

   s = 1/(1+np.exp(-Z))
   dZ = dA * s * (1-s)

   assert (dZ.shape == Z.shape)

   return dZ
```

Functions to do the linear backward activation :

```
def propa_arriere(dZ, cache):


   A_prev, W, b = cache
   m = A_prev.shape[1]


   dW = (1/2)*np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T)
   db = (1/2)*np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
   dA_prev = np.dot(W.T,dZ)


   assert (dA_prev.shape == A_prev.shape)
   assert (dW.shape == W.shape)
   assert (db.shape == b.shape)

   return dA_prev, dW, db

def propa_arriere_activ(dA, cache, activation):

   linear_cache, activation_cache = cache

   if activation == "relu":

      dZ = relu_backward(dA, activation_cache)
      dA_prev, dW, db = propa_arriere(dZ, linear_cache)


   elif activation == "sigmoid":

      dZ = sigmoid_backward(dA, activation_cache)
      dA_prev, dW, db = propa_arriere(dZ, linear_cache)


   return dA_prev, dW, db
```

Function to update the parameters :

```
def update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate):


   L = len(parameters) // 2 


   for i in reversed(range(1, L-1)): 
       parameters["W"+str(i)]=parameters["W"+str(i)] - learning_rate*grads["W"+str(i)]
       parameters["b"+str(i)]=parameters["b"+str(i)] - learning_rate*grads["b"+str(i)]
       parameters["A"+str(i)]=parameters["A"+str(i)] - learning_rate*grads["A"+str(i)]




   return parameters
```

The neural network function :

```
def two_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.05, num_iterations = 2000, print_cost=False):



   grads = {}
   costs = []                              # to keep track of the cost
   m = X.shape[1]                           # number of examples
   (n_x, n_h, n_y) = layers_dims


   parameters = init(n_x, n_h, n_y)



   W1 = parameters["W1"]
   b1 = parameters["b1"]
   W2 = parameters["W2"]
   b2 = parameters["b2"]



   for i in range(0, num_iterations):


       A1, cache1 = propa_avant_activ(X, W1, b1, activation = "relu")
       A2, cache2 = propa_avant_activ(A1, W2, b2, activation = "sigmoid")



       cost = fonction_cout(A2, Y)



       dA2 = (1/m)* (- (np.divide(Y, A2) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A2)))


       dA1, dW2, db2 = propa_arriere_activ(dA2, cache2, activation="sigmoid")
       dA0, dW1, db1 = propa_arriere_activ(dA1, cache1, activation="relu")



       grads['dW1'] = dW1
       grads['db1'] = db1
       grads['dW2'] = dW2
       grads['db2'] = db2


       parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)



       W1 = parameters["W1"]
       b1 = parameters["b1"]
       W2 = parameters["W2"]
       b2 = parameters["b2"]


       if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
           print("Cost after iteration {}: {}".format(i, np.squeeze(cost)))
       if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
           costs.append(cost)



   plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
   plt.ylabel('cost')
   plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
   plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
   plt.show()

   return parameters
```

Then I compute this line of code to run a neural network with an input shape of 64, a hidden layer of shape 20 and an output of shape 10 :

```
parameters = two_layer_model(x_train1, y_train1, layers_dims = (x_train1.shape[0], 20, 10), num_iterations = 2000, print_cost=True)
```

And I get this :

```
Cost after iteration 0: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 100: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 200: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 300: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 400: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 500: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 600: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 700: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 800: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 900: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1000: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1100: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1200: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1300: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1400: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1500: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1600: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1700: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1800: 6.962808001140989
Cost after iteration 1900: 6.962808001140989
```

And this graph :

[image: Cost after iteration]

Comment: I did the first unit of the Udacity Deep Learning nanodegree, so I'm perhaps only a bit further in than you.  It's been awhile though, and I think I'll need a bit more help from you in debugging your code.  I think the first thing we need to focus on is why the numbers aren't changing at all...  I'm at work, but maybe I can look at this later (once I've finished moving all my stuff out of my car to my new hotel room tonight).
How many times does it go through that for loop with the subtraction of grads["W"+str(i)], and what are the values of that?

Comment: It goes through that for loop 2 times because there's two layers ! len(parameters) = 4 and I divide it by 2.
The values of "grads" are the gradients of each parameters, so that this for loop updates each parameters

Comment: Ok I think that firstly the third line (in "update_parameters", to update the "A.." parameters) is useless because, these aren't parameters. When I delete this line, nothing change

Comment: Ok, I think that the problem is that the for loop doesn't compute because L=2 so "for i in reverse(range(1,L-1))" doesn't make sense

Comment: So I change L-1 by L+1 and I get this error :

'<ipython-input-144-fcdc5ee230d0> in update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
      6 
      7     for i in reversed(range(1, L+1)):
----> 8         parameters["W"+str(i)]=parameters["W"+str(i)] - learning_rate*grads["W"+str(i)]
      9         parameters["b"+str(i)]=parameters["b"+str(i)] - learning_rate*grads["b"+str(i)]
     10 

KeyError: 'W2'

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't compute "W2"

Comment: OK I've just understood, the problem is that in "grads" I put "W" + str(i) instead of "dW" +str(i).
It just computed perfectly :DDD Thank you for your help, you have asked the good questions !!